# ImportError: cannot import name GstRtspServer, introspection typelib not found

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, gstreamer, gobject-introspection

Im trying to get a simple GstRtspServer program working on an external amazon linux EC2 server at the moment, but I am having serious issues getting it to actually run. No matter what I do I keep getting this same error when I try to run it, even if the program is reduced only to

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst','1.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gst, GstRtspServer
```

I have pygobject installed, I have gstreamer installed, I have gobject-introspection installed, and any google results have been wildly non helpful. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: GstRtspServer as an additional extra package that needs to be installed.

Answer (score 12):

Specifically, on Ubuntu 16.04 one would have to install the package **gir1.2-gst-rtsp-server-1.0**, which contains the introspection typelib.

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gst-rtsp-server-1.0
```

Comment: This also solves the problem on LFT - ubuntu 18 on jetsons.

Answer (score 0):

I use MSYS2 MINGW64 on Windows, I solved with

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-rtsp-server
```